# HTTP request using Python Requests library and Pandas to convert dataframes to multiline and nested json objects

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I'm working on an issue when sending a POST request to Web App using Databricks and requests library. As a result of multiple group by and join operations, I have a complex dataframe data to be sent in the body of the request and I'm getting an error when running to_json() method.

When converted, the result dataframe looks like a multiline json object, as [in databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-json.html#multi-line-mode). It follows an example to clarify:

```
[{
    "string": "str1",
    "object": [{
        "string": "str2",
        "dict": {
            "string": "str3"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Or:

```
    [
     {"string":"str1", "object":[{"string":"str2","dict":{"string":"str3"}}]}
    ]
```

As mentioned, dataframe includes multiline json object as field, producing a nested and complex object that is loaded to MongoDB as a result with success and I'm trying to add to a request's body and send to API.

During tests, the requests library works well when using a simple multiline json object or just single json objects as follows. I can not move on from this point on when trying to convert dataframes with multiline json objects within this original object.

See the code that is working:

```
import json
import requests

try:
  body = {"items": [{"string": "str1", "Date": "04/2021", "Int": 1000 }]}
  response = requests.post('URL',data=json.dumps(body))

print(response.json())
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
print(errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
print(errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
print(errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
print(err)
```

Now, it follows an example that is not and I'm trying to make it work:

```
import json
import requests

try:
  body = {"items":[{"string":"str1", "object":[{"string":"str2","dict":{"string":"str3"}}]}]}
  response = requests.post('URL',data=json.dumps(body))

print(response.json())
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
print(errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
print(errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
print(errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
print(err)
```

In the original code, when configuring the request, I used to use Pandas to convert dataframe values to nested json objects using df.to_json() but I'm getting an error saying it's unable to convert and Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow. It follows Pandas to_json() [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

Going deeper, and looking at documentation I realized there are some parametrizations I can use but none helped. One of the approaches I tried, "to_json" method replaces the json multiline objects with lists, skipping keys and including values only. Even if I try to send data in this way, I got an issue showing it's unable to convert the field "object" (list-converted) as above.

Using spark command below:

```
df.repartition(1).write.mode("overWrite").option("multiLine","true").json("file.json")
```

I'm able to write json files that seems to be fine, as expected. Now, I'm checking if somehow I can read from saved json files and see If I could load data in the post request's body as originally desired.

Does anyone can help or can see what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Felipe Regis.

Comment: your two sections of code look okay, I think df to JSON needs to be looked up. for section 2 there were few }] were missing. so made `body = {"items":[{"string":"str1", "object":[{"string":"str2","dict":{"string":"str3"}}]}]}` and then output from both section came as follows `{"items": [{"string": "str1", "Date": "04/2021", "Int": 1000}]}` and `{"items": [{"string": "str1", "object": [{"string": "str2", "dict": {"string": "str3"}}]}]}`

Comment: @simpleApp, my mistake when typing code here on section 2, just added "}]". tks

Comment: You are not showing the error, but I guess you have to send some headers, or even some authentication.